# how to know sftp file transfer speed and time taken

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib, net-sftp, ssh2-sftp

Is there a way to calculate the time taken & the speed for downloading/uploading a file via `sftp` in php as similar to the below?

```
$sftp->get('filename', 'local/filename'); //gets the file
$sftp->size('filename'); //gives the size of the file.
```

These two commands fetches the file & gives the size..in that way can we calculate the speed & time taken?

Comment: The question should be asked after at least minimal effort has been made to do something yourself.

Comment: phpseclib's complex logs show how long each packet took to send receive. I suppose you could manually add each of those values up..

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Thank you very much, we can create in any number of ways as we like but following/trying to know some existing functions is not a bad practice. This is what I've asked there..that do we have some way through sftp?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, you have all the data you need: time and size.

```
$start = time();

$sftp->get('filename', 'local/filename'); //gets the file
$size = $sftp->size('filename'); //gives the size of the file.

$timeTakenInSeconds = time() - $start;
echo sprintf('Bytes/second: %d', $size / $timeTakenInSeconds);
```

Comment: I mean do we have any function in sftp to give this information?

Comment: @kumar: I don't know, take a look into the documentation. What is the problem with using your own measurement?